# Data Extraction in matrix form in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix, data-extraction

I need to make a matrix by extracting certain information from a file called **flowdata**. I need to extract the **meanValue** of all **inputGroup == 5**. As the column names, I need the corresponding information on the "name" column, and as row names I need the information written on the cell 4 above the "inputGroup == 5" [i-4]. In this case "Methanol, at plant"

**Here is the link to the dropbox that has the data**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/x2knuqq1odbt5zg/flowdata01.txt?dl=0

Here is the R code I have:

```
flowdata <-flowdata01

    in.up = length(unique(flowdata$name)) # number of unit processes
    in.p = length(unique(flowdata$.attrs[which(flowdata$metadata=='name')])) # number of inputs/outputs

    input.mat = matrix(0, in.p,in.up) #empty matrix

    colnames(input.mat) = unique(flowdata$name) # up names
    rownames(input.mat) = unique(flowdata$attrs[which(flowdata$metadata=='name')]) # inputs/outputs names

    for (i in 1:nrow(flowdata)){ # for every row in flowdata

      if (flowdata$metadata[i]=="inputGroup" && flowdata$attrs[i] == 5){ # if it is an inputGroup 5 

        col.name = flowdata$name[i] # up name
        row.name = flowdata$attrs[i-4] # i/o name 4 cells above

        value = as.numeric(flowdata$attrs[i-5]) #value 5 cells above

        input.mat[row.name,col.name] = value}}

input.mat = input.mat[-which(rowSums(input.mat)==0),] # if the row is empty, then the flow was an input or output of no interest
```

`

When I run the above R code, I get this error message:

```
  Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, row.name, col.name, value = 6397) : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

[This is how the matrix should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbPZN.jpg)

Comment: Please add some sample data to your question, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: data are added as HTML format

Comment: You need to share the data in a reproducible way. As it is, getting the data into R is a hassle that could drive away potential answerers.

Comment: I added the dropbox link to the data.